# How to detect if a PC Booted from CD/DVD or USB

Tags: windows, security, bios

Hi I want to know is there a way that I can check whether someone booted my PC with a CD/DVD or USB with a live operating system.
Because this way anyone can steal my PC data.

And please guide me how can I protect my data from such theft, One way I know is BIOS password but that password can be reset by removing the battery from motherboard.

Comment: Full disk encryption will prevent extracting data when booting an alternate operating system

Answer (score 1):

first possibility is like you said to put a password in your BIOS.
protect your computer with a lock (or something else) to prevent opening for removing the battery.

if your lock or security system is broken you will be able to know that someone tried or did something.